# change coding style to avoid nested if-blocks

Tags: c++, nested-if

I'm coding an openGL-based application and I'm using various flags, if-blocks and counters to control the appearance of certain objects within my drawing loop. E.g. the following fragment is from a function (called from my major drawing loop on each iteration) that is responsible for capturing a photo once a face is detected: it will first print some text instructions and 3-2-1-done countdown, etc.

```
if (auto face = detect_face(video_frame, draw_frames_flag_m)) { // detect face
  helper::gl::display_cv_mat(video_frame); // display face
  face_out_of_range_msg_flag_m = false;
  if (!photo_capture_flag_m) { // start capturing 
    photo_capture_flag_m = true;
    capture_counter_m = glfwGetTime() + 5 + WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_PHOTOS; 
  } else if (glfwGetTime() < (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time4)) {
    draw_frames_flag_m = true;
    render_text("Face detected! Look at the camera and stand still",10,window_height_m-76);
  } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time3))
    render_text("3",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
  else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time2)) 
    render_text("2",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
  else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time1)) 
    render_text("1",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
  else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_almost_done)) {
    render_text("done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
    draw_frames_flag_m = false; // don't draw frames the next few times so that the photo can be taken
  } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_done)) {
    render_text("done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
    load_and_save_portait(video_frame, *face);
  } else if (glfwGetTime() < capture_counter_m - 1) 
    render_text("...processing photo..",(window_width_m/2)-50,window_height_m/2);
  else { // reset
    photo_capture_flag_m = false;
    capture_done_flag_m = false;    
  }
} else {
  helper::gl::display_cv_mat(video_frame);
  if (photo_capture_flag_m) photo_capture_flag_m = false;
  if (capture_done_flag_m) capture_done_flag_m = false;
}
```

This code relies on other member variables/functions and some global constants, etc which are not given here since it's not the functionality that bothers me but the structure and this is already evident here. I find code like this awful: nested loops are difficult to read and we are not in the 80s in the end of day.. but unfortunately I find myself writing code like this very often..

What bothers me is that the nested loops here suggest some sort of polymorphic behaviour - in each iteration of the global drawing loop I have a video_frame visualised but each time along with a number of additional elements such as text, borders, etc. So there has to be a way to structure the code around polymorphic objects of some sort.

I've been thinking about class-inheritance which does works in other cases (e.g. drawing a different series of shapes) - yet it doesn't seem to be plausible herein. I thought, e.g. of having a `VideoFrameAbstractClass` as the common interface to a series of subclasses such as `VideoFrame3`, `VideoFrame2`, `VideoFrameProcessingImage` etc, then pass the video_frame along with the counters to the common interface and let the overridden drawing functions do the drawing. However, this approach seems even more silly to me.. I can't justify a whole new class simply because a text message changes from "3" to "2" to "1".. let aside that it'd be probably slower and with more overhead this way.

I'd be interested in hearing people's thoughts on this.

Comment: You should start with proper indentation to make the code more readable. Also what have all of these tags to do with your question actually? I'm going to remove these now.

Comment: "What bothers me is that the nested loops here" -- `if` and `else if` are not loops

Comment: And they are not really nested. You only have one level of nesting, which is fine. I guess you may mean all the if-else statements. In your case you may want to use or write a generic timer - so that you can register an event to execute in n milliseconds, this event at the end would restart the timer with the next event and so on (currently if you want to extend some step you need to change all the `wait_times` rather than just one). Another option in OOP world is to use the chain of responsibility pattern, though I think in your case it would only make the code more obscure.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>   } else if (glfwGetTime() < (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time4)) {
>     draw_frames_flag_m = true;
>     render_text("Face detected! Look at the camera and stand still",10,window_height_m-76);
>   } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time3))
>     render_text("3",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
>   else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time2)) 
>     render_text("2",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
>   else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time1)) 
>     render_text("1",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
>   else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_almost_done)) {
>     render_text("done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
>     draw_frames_flag_m = false; // don't draw frames the next few times so that the photo can be taken
>   } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_done)) {
>     render_text("done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
>     load_and_save_portait(video_frame, *face);
>   } else if (glfwGetTime() < capture_counter_m - 1) 
>     render_text("...processing photo..",(window_width_m/2)-50,window_height_m/2);
>   else { // reset
> ```

This series of `if`s all have in common that they check if the value returned by `glfwGetTime()` is not greater than a certain other value.

Conceptually, this constitutes a range with certain bounds in it, mapped to operations.

In other words, a `std::map<int, std::function<void()>`, on which you can call the [`upper_bound` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound).

Here is a full working toy example:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void render_text(std::string const& s, int a, int b, int c )
{
    std::cout << s << " " << a << b << c << "\n";
}

void load_and_save_portait()
{
    std::cout << "load_and_save_portait\n";
}

int main()
{
    int glfwGetTime = 90;
    bool draw_frames_flag_m = false;
    int window_width_m = 0;
    int window_height_m = 0;
    int capture_counter_m = 0;
    int photos_wait_time3 = 0;
    int photos_wait_time2 = -100;
    int photos_wait_time1 = -99;
    int photos_wait_time_almost_done = 0;
    int photos_wait_time_done = 0;

    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> range = {
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time3, [&]() { render_text("3",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200); } },
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time2, [&]() { render_text("2",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200); } },
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time1, [&]() { render_text("1",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200); } },
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_almost_done, [&] {
            render_text("done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
            draw_frames_flag_m = false; // don't draw frames the next few times so that the photo can be taken
        }},
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_done, [&]() {
            render_text("done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200);
            load_and_save_portait();
        }}
    };

    auto const upper_bound_iter = range.upper_bound(glfwGetTime);
    if (upper_bound_iter != range.end()) {
        auto const function = upper_bound_iter->second;
        function();
    } else {
        std::cout << "no match\n";
    }

}
```

Now, of course you may find additional ways to make this more concise. For example, there may be a certain pattern in the different operations which could be generalised. Ignoring the boolean flags and the `load_and_save_portait` call for a moment, it seems that all operations call `render_text`. So instead of the map storing `std::function` objects, you may as well store the arguments to `render_text`:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct render_text_arguments
{
    std::string s;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void render_text(std::string const& s, int a, int b, int c )
{
    std::cout << s << " " << a << b << c << "\n";
}

void render_text(render_text_arguments const& arguments)
{
    render_text(arguments.s, arguments.a, arguments.b, arguments.c);
}

int main()
{
    int glfwGetTime = 90;
    int window_width_m = 0;
    int window_height_m = 0;
    int capture_counter_m = 0;
    int photos_wait_time3 = 0;
    int photos_wait_time2 = -100;
    int photos_wait_time1 = -99;
    int photos_wait_time_almost_done = 0;
    int photos_wait_time_done = 0;

    std::map<int, render_text_arguments> range = {
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time3,            { "3",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200    }},
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time2,            { "2",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200    }},
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time1,            { "1",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200    }},
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_almost_done, { "done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200 }},
        { capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_done,        { "done",window_width_m/2,window_height_m/2,200 }}
    };

    auto const upper_bound_iter = range.upper_bound(glfwGetTime);
    if (upper_bound_iter != range.end()) {
        auto const arguments = upper_bound_iter->second;
        render_text(arguments);
    } else {
        std::cout << "no match\n";
    }
}
```

These are all ideas. You must judge if and how they are applicable to your problem.

---

Note that what we've done here is turning hard-wired program logic into possibly dynamic run-time data. You can easily add and remove items from the map, or perhaps even do such elaborate things as reading them from a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is not really the level of nested `if`s.

While technically, `else if` adds one level of nesting, the idiom is common enough such that it will be understood as case selection. The key point here is to use proper formatting. I recommend that if some of your clauses need curly braces, you use them for all. Otherwise, the control flow is much harder to grasp visually. It might also help if you adopt a coding style where you use more indentation than two characters per level.

The other problem with the code in question is that it is just too complex, no matter what control flow construct you use. While a simple case selection like

```
if (std::strcmp("alpha", text) == 0) {
    return get_alpha();
} else if (std::strcmp("beta", text) == 0) {
    return get_beta();
} else if (std::strcmp("gamma", text) == 0) {
    return get_gamma();
} else if ( … ) {
    …
} else {
    throw std::invalid_argument {};
}
```

is easy to follow even if the number of cases becomes large (it is basically a `switch` over a string except that C++ can't do that natively), your function contains too much complicated logic. Try refactoring it and break it into multiple functions.

For example, start with the outer `if`.

```
if (auto face = detect_face(video_frame, draw_frames_flag_m)) {
    handle_face(face);
} else {
    helper::gl::display_cv_mat(video_frame);
    if (photo_capture_flag_m) {
        photo_capture_flag_m = false;
    }
    if (capture_done_flag_m) {
        capture_done_flag_m = false;
    }
}
```

This code is no longer hard to follow.

Now you can turn your attention to the extracted `handle_face` function. Once formatted properly…

```
void handle_face(face_t * face) {
    helper::gl::display_cv_mat(video_frame);  // display face
    face_out_of_range_msg_flag_m = false;
    if (!photo_capture_flag_m) {
        // start capturing
        photo_capture_flag_m = true;
        capture_counter_m = glfwGetTime() + 5 + WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_PHOTOS;
    } else if (glfwGetTime() < (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time4)) {
        draw_frames_flag_m = true;
        render_text("Face detected; look at the camera and stand still.", 10, window_height_m - 76);
    } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time3)) {
        render_text("3", window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
    } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time2)) {
        render_text("2", window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
    } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time1)) {
        render_text("1", window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
    } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_almost_done)) {
        render_text("done", window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
        draw_frames_flag_m = false;
        // Don't draw frames the next few times so that the photo can be taken
    } else if (glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_time_done)) {
        render_text("done", window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
        load_and_save_portait(video_frame, *face);
    } else if (glfwGetTime() < capture_counter_m - 1) {
        render_text("processing photo...", (window_width_m / 2) - 50, window_height_m / 2);
    } else {  // reset
        photo_capture_flag_m = false;
        capture_done_flag_m = false;
    }
}
```

…it doesn't look *that* daunting any more.

Of course, there is still room for improvement. For example, you're repeating

```
render_text("…", window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
```

quite a bit. Since the only thing that is changing is the first argument, why not have a helper function?

```
void render_text_center(const char * text) {
    render_text(text, window_width_m / 2, window_height_m / 2, 200);
}
```

And the various

```
glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - photos_wait_timeX)
```

tests could be wrapped into a function

```
bool before_wait_time(const wait_time_t wt) {
    return glfwGetTime() <= (capture_counter_m - wt);
}
```

Now we get this.

```
void handle_face(face_t * face) {
    helper::gl::display_cv_mat(video_frame);  // display face
    face_out_of_range_msg_flag_m = false;
    if (!photo_capture_flag_m) {
        // start capturing
        photo_capture_flag_m = true;
        capture_counter_m = glfwGetTime() + 5 + WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_PHOTOS;
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time4)) {
        draw_frames_flag_m = true;
        render_text_top_left("Face detected; look at the camera and stand still.");
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time3)) {
        render_text_center("3");
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time2)) {
        render_text_center("2");
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time1)) {
        render_text_center("1");
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time_almost_done)) {
        render_text_center("done");
        draw_frames_flag_m = false;
        // Don't draw frames the next few times so that the photo can be taken
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time_done)) {
        render_text_center("done");
        load_and_save_portait(video_frame, *face);
    } else if (before_wait_time(capture_counter_m)) {
        render_text_center_right("processing photo...");
    } else {  // reset
        photo_capture_flag_m = false;
        capture_done_flag_m = false;
    }
}
```

While it didn't reduce the lines of code or the number of `if`s, the simpler code has less distractions and is easier to parse for the human eye.

Now we can actually see the root cause of the complicated code. What we have is basically a loop written down as an `if … else if … else` cascade. I don't know enough about the rest of your program logic to tell for sure how you'll go about refactoring this but it seems very likely to me that you could remove all those `photos_wait_timeX` variables and the corresponding `if`s – which, in all fairness, are only three here – and instead compute the interval.

```
int get_current_step() {
    // I'm not sure whether your logic actually works that way…
    return (glfwGetTime() - capture_counter_m) / WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_PHOTOS;
}

void handle_face(face_t * face) {
    helper::gl::display_cv_mat(video_frame);  // display face
    face_out_of_range_msg_flag_m = false;
    if (!photo_capture_flag_m) {
        // start capturing
        photo_capture_flag_m = true;
        capture_counter_m = glfwGetTime() + 5 + WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_PHOTOS;
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time4)) {
        draw_frames_flag_m = true;
        render_text_top_left("Face detected; look at the camera and stand still.");
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time1)) {
        const auto step = get_step();
        render_text_center(std::to_string(step).c_str());
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time_almost_done)) {
        render_text_center("done");
        draw_frames_flag_m = false;
        // Don't draw frames the next few times so that the photo can be taken
    } else if (before_wait_time(photos_wait_time_done)) {
        render_text_center("done");
        load_and_save_portait(video_frame, *face);
    } else if (before_wait_time(capture_counter_m)) {
        render_text_center_right("processing photo...");
    } else {  // reset
        photo_capture_flag_m = false;
        capture_done_flag_m = false;
    }
}
```

This is still not pretty code but I'd consider it acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon @πάντα ῥεῖ answer, you can also use the good old `goto`. Normal caveats of `goto` still apply, though.

```
if (!firstCondition) {
    goto done;
}

// Do something.

if (!secondCondition) {
    goto done;
}

// Do something.

done:
    // End here.
```

Comment: +1 for being honest about your use of `goto`. It doesn't become better when dressed up as `do … while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One commonly used technique to avoid deeply nested `if`/`else if` cascades is to use a `do {} while(false);` and `break` out before checking the next condition.

Instead of having code like

```
if(firstCondition) {
   // Do something
}
else {
   if(secondCondition) {
        // Do something
   }
}
```

You can write

```
do {
    if(!firstCondition) {
         break;
    }

    // Do something

    if(!secondCondition) {
         break;
    }

    // Do something

    // ...
} while(false);
```